# Adding value labels at the end of the plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot the labels in the plot. I did that but they don't really lok very good. Here's an example to better understand it, I have this plot:
[image]

And I want to add the values in the end, I did that but they look strange: 
[image]

Is there any way of how I could fix this? I do the plotting at the end of the code where it is commented `#plotting`.
Here is the reproducible code:

```
library(glmnet)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
set.seed(100)
n=100
p=50
X=matrix(rnorm(n*p), nrow=n)
y=matrix(rnorm(n), nrow=n)
lam = seq(0.1,7,length.out=100)
lm=glmnet(X,y,alpha=1,lambda=lam, intercept=FALSE, standardize=FALSE)
value1=as.matrix(coef(lm))

#creating a dataframe
L1 <- function(x)
  sum(abs(x))
bind_cols(
  as.data.frame(value1) %>%
    summarise_all(funs(L1(.))) %>%
    t() %>%
    as.data.frame() %>%
    rename(x = V1),
  t(value1) %>%
    as.data.frame() %>%
    rename_all(funs(gsub("V", "", .)))
) %>%
  gather(row, y, 2:(nrow(value1) + 1)) -> dataf

#plotting 
ggplot(dataf, aes(x, y, colour = row)) + geom_line() +
  geom_text_repel(
    data = subset(dataf, x == max(x)),
    aes(label = row),
    size = 2,
    nudge_x = 1 
  ) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main thing going on here is that you have a bunch of text labels all in one spot, so by repelling them and letting them have segments attaching labels to their values, you end up with this starburst at the end of your plot.

To see what I mean, filter your data for the maximum x value, which is where you're placing your label, and rows where y == 0: there's 35 of these! So you have 35 bits of text all vying for the same spot and being repelled away from one another.

```r
dataf %>% 
  filter(x == max(x), y == 0) %>%
  nrow()
#> [1] 35
```

Second way you can see this is if you set the color of the segments connecting the texts to their values. If you set it to gray, you can distinguish those segments from the actual `geom_line`s, since now they aren't the same color.

```r
ggplot(dataf, aes(x, y, colour = row)) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_text_repel(
    data = . %>% filter(x == max(x)),
    aes(label = row),
    size = 2,
    nudge_x = 0.01,
    segment.color = "gray60"
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = expand_scale(mult = c(0.05, 0.1))) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

Here are a couple ways you can avoid this tangle: I decreased the `nudge_x` so the texts would be closer to the lines (`nudge_x` works in relation to your x values, so nudging over by 1 when values are only 0 to 0.6ish puts the labels very far away). I changed the segment color to something neutral, and adjusted the minimum distance before the segments are drawn. I added a `expand_scale` to give some more space on the right side (this is only in the dev version of ggplot still). And most importantly, I took out labels for values of 0.

You should probably tweak these things to your liking, but hopefully this is a start in cleaning it up.

```r
ggplot(dataf, aes(x, y, colour = row)) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_text_repel(
    data = . %>% filter(x == max(x), y != 0),
    aes(label = row),
    size = 2,
    nudge_x = 0.01,
    min.segment.length = 5,
    segment.color = "gray60"
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = expand_scale(mult = c(0.05, 0.1))) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

Created on 2018-06-11 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: thank you a lot, just a small question, I've never seen this function before `expand_scale` is this part of package `ggdag` ? because I can't really install it

Comment: No, it's in the dev version of ggplot2, which you can get from github. I believe it will be in the next CRAN release of ggplot2 next month, but the dev version is fairly stable

Comment: I installed these, `install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
dev_mode(on=T)
install_github("hadley/ggplot2")` but I'm still getting an error `could not find function "expand_scale"` could you please write what you installed for the dev version

Comment: Try it from the [tidyverse github](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2), and restart R. But also it isn't essential to expand the scale, it's just helpful for creating more space to fit the labels in